# Put zeros in front of a number to make it 4 digits

Tags: python

I have a number of four or fewer digits, e.g. `8` or `12` or `197`. I'd like to put 0's in front of this number until it is 4 digits long, e.g. `0008` or `0012` or `0197`. What would be the easiest way to go about this in Python? What would be the most "Pythonic"?

I could do a series of if statements, like so:

```
if len(number) == 1:
    number = '000' + number
...
```

But I have a feeling there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Several Pythonic ways to do this, I am really liking the new f-strings as of Python 3.6:

```
>>> f'{5:04}'
'0005'
```

This uses the string formatting minilanguage:

```
>>> five = 5
>>> f'{five:04}'
'0005'
```

The first zero means the fill, the 4 means to which width:

```
>>> minimum_width = 4
>>> filler = "0" # could also be just 0
>>> f'{five:{filler}{minimum_width}}'
'0005'
```

Next using the builtin format function:

```
>>> format(5, "04")
'0005'
>>> format(55, "04") 
'0055'
>>> format(355, "04")
'0355'
```

Also, the string format method with the minilanguage:

```
>>> '{0:04}'.format(5)
'0005'
```

Again, the specification comes after the :, and the 0 means fill with zeros and the 4 means a width of four.

Finally, the str.zfill method is custom made for this, and probably the fastest way to do it:

```
>>> str(5).zfill(4)
'0005'
```